# Generic value editor GUI for dictionaries in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

Say I have a dictionary full of parameters:

```
{speed = 1, intelligence = 3, dexterity = 2}
```

I want to call a loop that creates a `Label` and a `SpinBox` for each item in this list procedurally, in case I want to add more attributes later. I can create the window and return the updated values just fine. My only issue is that I want all the widgets to be created as necessary, whether I have 7 or 20 attributes to edit.

So the label object could be called `speed_Label` and the intelligence label object `intelligence_Label`, and the spinbox containing the value of speed would be `speed_SpinBox` and so on, which then I could pass back easily. However, this

a) seems like poor naming practice

b) seems difficult seeing as I can't find out how to give objects names procedurally, say

```
for KEY in dict.keys(): # say the KEY is "Speed"
    # this would produce a Label object called Speed_Label
    # which displays the text "Speed"
    "KEY" + "_Label" = QLabel("KEY")
```

Comment: Do you _need_ the objects to have the names as if you were naming them all by hand? You could simply have an array or dictionary of these widgets and index them by number or string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use a list or dict?

Something like this should work:

```
widgets = {}
form = QFormLayout()
for key, value in your_dict.iteritems():
    widgets[key] = widget = {}
    widget['spinbox'] = spinbox = QSpinBox()
    spinbox.setValue(value)
    form.addRow(key, spinbox)
```